# Getting access denied on accessing TFRecords for training a Deep Learning model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am training a model using the Google QuickDraw dataset. I have stored the data from ndjson to tfrecords as instructed in the tutorial for it. Then I used the code provided by Google [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/quickdraw/train_model.py) for training the dataset using those tfrecords. But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1334, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1319, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: A:\Code\Machine Learning\Software Engineering project\Quick Draw\TFRecord Train dataset : Access is denied.

; Input/output error
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext}} = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,1], [?,?], [?,2], [?,1]], output_types=[DT_INT64, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext/_317}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_20_IteratorGetNext", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:\Code\Machine Learning\Software Engineering project\Quick Draw\Train_Model.py", line 303, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "A:\Code\Machine Learning\Software Engineering project\Quick Draw\Train_Model.py", line 214, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 471, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 610, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 711, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 354, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1207, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1241, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1471, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 671, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1156, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1255, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1240, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1312, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1076, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1152, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1328, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1348, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: A:\Code\Machine Learning\Software Engineering project\Quick Draw\TFRecord Train dataset : Access is denied.

; Input/output error
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at A:\Code\Machine Learning\Software Engineering project\Quick Draw\Train_Model.py:70)  = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,1], [?,?], [?,2], [?,1]], output_types=[DT_INT64, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext/_317}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_20_IteratorGetNext", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'IteratorGetNext', defined at:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 144, in main
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 474, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "A:\Code\Machine Learning\Software Engineering project\Quick Draw\Train_Model.py", line 303, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "A:\Code\Machine Learning\Software Engineering project\Quick Draw\Train_Model.py", line 214, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 471, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 610, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 711, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 354, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1207, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1234, in _train_model_default
    input_fn, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN))
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1075, in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
    self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode))
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1162, in _call_input_fn
    return input_fn(**kwargs)
  File "A:\Code\Machine Learning\Software Engineering project\Quick Draw\Train_Model.py", line 70, in input_func
    features, labels = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 421, in get_next
    name=name)), self._output_types,
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py", line 2108, in iterator_get_next
    output_shapes=output_shapes, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1770, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

UnknownError (see above for traceback): NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: A:\Code\Machine Learning\Software Engineering project\Quick Draw\TFRecord Train dataset : Access is denied.

; Input/output error
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at A:\Code\Machine Learning\Software Engineering project\Quick Draw\Train_Model.py:70)  = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,1], [?,?], [?,2], [?,1]], output_types=[DT_INT64, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext/_317}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_20_IteratorGetNext", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

I am not getting exactly which function is giving the error. So, I have not posted my code, as I don't know the relevant part of it. But why is the access is denied? I have used almost the same code as given in the repository. Also, I am not getting what the error is about, is it just access denied or something else? Please help me that.

Comment: It does seem to be something related to your particular setup - for some reason the Python process is not being able to access that path. Have you tried moving the data files to a different path (e.g. `A:\data`, or in a different drive unit) and see if it works?

Comment: @jdehesa I tried it. Still getting same error.

Comment: Try checking your tfrecords file with `tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator('filename.tfrecords')`

Comment: @Sharky the thing is, in the dataset creation code given by Google, which converts ndjson to tfrecords, the storing in tfrecords is done with shards and the shard no. is included into file name. So the filenames are like `train.tfrecord-1-of-10` . So, can that be a problem? I think the os.path.join did not join the path name properly and it is supposed to be `train-1-of-10.tfrecord`

Comment: I' guess you can just do `filename + .tfrecords` just to make sure files are not corrupted

Comment: @Sharky it is working when I use tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator() but that code is still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the file you are accessing has proper extension `".tfrecords"`.

This issue occurs when the file it is trying to access with does not have proper extension.